# Too many triangles causing app to exit

Tags: opengl-es

I am using opengles to display a LOT of triangles.
When I run the app on my phone (a Samsung mini) if I display more than about 5,000 triangles the app exits as soon as it attempts to draw. There is no error message, it just exits. Anything between 4 and 5k triangles runs on the phone but the screen flashes white occasionally as I move the camera.
I assume this is a limitation of the phones abilities. It works fine on my Asus tablet. 
My question is simply do you agree that this a limitation of the phone?
I have not included any code here because as I say it works fine on the tablet.
If you agree I will see what I can do to optimize the code.
Many thanks for your time folks.

Comment: This cannot be a limitation of the driver (atleast not in terms of # of triangles), as the phone runs several other more complex 3D benchmarks and it has a reasonably high screen resolution. You should post code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm at work now but will post code later. Cheers